# Simple using Map with Lists as value

Tags: java, spring, collections, java-8, guava

I am using concurrent hash map like this:

```
private final Map<String, List<FooObject>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

I am using List of my custom objects as value. When application started and I need store some object into List for specific key in map, I need at first check, if there are some value (List) for that key:

```
FooObject foo = new Foo(...);

if (map.get(key) == null) {
   map.putIfAbsent(key, Lists.newArrayList(foo))
} else {
   map.get(key).add(foo);
}
```

My question is if there are way to write code above more simpler? With some java 8 feature? I am also using guava and spring in project, so if there some utility in that frameworks it is still fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: When you call `map.get(key).add(foo);`, you introduce concurrency problem because your `List` is not synchronized.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn ou, I thought when I am using ConcurrentHashMap, objects in it will be aslo thread safe :/

Comment: It is threadsafe to get/set the `Map` values, not the content of the value.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn thank you for warning ... I found FastArrayList https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/FastArrayList.html 
do you think is it good alternative?

Comment: @DenisStephanov I believe that the best way to eliminate that if-else is to replace it with `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(foo);`

Comment: @DenisStephanov Ah, I just read that you need concurrency. Then perhaps my comment above isn't so appropriate. :)

According to this Guava comment: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/135#issuecomment-306172853, using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` over Apache Commons Collections' `FastArrayList` _should_ be fine.

Comment: @DenisStephanov Alternatively, it sounds to me like you're trying to create a concurrent multimap, so Guava's `Multimaps.synchronizedListMultimap(MultimapBuilder.hashKeys().arrayListValues().build())` may work for your case. :)